# How to pull more than 1mb data from mysql column using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3Mb string data in mysql column. When I run a SQL query at mysql prompt it returns complete data. But from php I am unable to fetch complete data, it is returning only 1mb of data data.

my mysql configs have `max_allowed_packet_size=33554432`

PHP `max_post_size=30mb` and `memory_limit=300mb`

Comment: 3 MB in a single TEXT field is typically a strong hint that your data storage concept needs improvement.

Comment: Maybe you could use `SUBSTR` as a quick fix..?

`SELECT SUBSTR(huge_text, 1, 33554432) AS part_1 FROM table`, then `SUBSTR(huge_text, 33554433, 33554432) AS part_2 FROM table;`, etc...

Comment: @nbrogi 33554432 is 32Mb. The OP wants to retrieve 3Mb. So using SUBSTR as you suggest will always return (or attempt to) the entire value.

Comment: Ah, got it I got that from the question. Then you put 1MB—would that work..? I'm not sure, it was just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using PDO?
The problem may be that the insert buffer default value is 1[MiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

To change it, update the line used to connect to the database by adding the new value for the parameter `MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE`:

```
$pdo = new PDO("your connection_settings", "user", "pass", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE=>1024*1024*5));
```

In this example, the new size of the buffer will be 5[MiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

[See this page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-max-buffer-size) for more information about this attribute.

Comment: Yes I am using PDO, from my framework i am calling PDO objects.Your solution is working fine. Thanks